# PHP microtime()

Tags: php, microtime

Here is my code:

```
<?
    $time = microtime();
    $len = strlen($time);
    echo $time;
    echo"<br>".$len."<br>";
    $micro;
    $i = 0;
    while ($time{$i} != " ")
    {
        $micro{i}=$time{i};
        echo $micro{i};
        $i=$i+1;
    }
?>
```

The output I'm getting is 0000000000 (that is $micro). Here I'm trying to get the microseconds part of the output.

Is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `microtime(true)` instead.

```
$time = microtime(true);
$micro = $time - floor($time); // microseconds part
```

Comment: @MPV: do you know other function that can help in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Use $micro{$i}=$time{$i}; instead of $micro{i}=$time{i};

But much better way to do stuff like this:

list($timestamp, $microseconds) = split(" ", microtime());